# Bypassing the "Get Directions" button in GMaps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, maps

So i have an intent like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=38.757982,-9.153193"));
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(intent);
```

And `onClick` it opens the GMaps app but it appears the coordinates textbox, and the user must still press "Get Directions" in order for them to be generated.

Is there a way i can bypass this "Get Directions" button so when the intent starts it generates the directions without the user having to click "Get Directions" ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I wanted the starting point to be the current location of the user.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a starting address (`saddr`) in your URI, so maps it is prompting the user for the start address.  If you want directions from the current location, add `&saddr=Current+Location` to your URI like this --

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=38.757982,-9.153193&saddr=Current+Location"));
```

Comment: That does a search for "Current Location" it doesn't actually say to GMaps i want to start where i'm at. At least when i try it it says "Did you mean: Current TV / Current Catalog / Current Inc"

Comment: It works for me (at least here in the US).  The current location is auto populated assuming it is available.  It might be a localization problem with the string "Current+Location".  If you know the location in your app, you can always replace "Current+Location" with the coordinates.

Comment: Well, i tried "My+Location" and "Current+Location" and none of those work. I'm testing with the Emulator, being US and still doesn't work.